# Positioning of the product div gets messy

Tags: css, html

You see, the page's supposed to look like this:

http://www.whybaguio.com/php/shop/shoplistings.php?arrange=default

But there are pages that looks like this:
http://www.whybaguio.com/php/eat/eatlistings.php?arrange=default

I think I know that the categories div's the culprit... but do you know any way I could fix it without making the font smaller for the categories again? :(

I hope you get what I mean.. thanks!

Comment: In what browser are you viewing the site. In Firefox it looks fine.

Comment: I'm using firefox @Brainfeeder

Comment: please click the next button, and you will find a messy page :(

Comment: Is it not only messing up when the thumbnail is missing?

Comment: nope. it's messing up when the categories are too long :( like "Video and DVD Sales and Rentals" @BillyMoat

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but why do you load jquery 3 times ?
And the lay-out gets messy not only if it's a long text. You could try to wrap your items in a `<div class="row"></div>` like bootstrap does. 
This would help you if it IS a text length issue as well. Because your second row will stay under the first, which has the height of the tallest item inside. Hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look at your site, the right navigation button is too far over pushing the columns down. And when the images are missing it causes the element below it to move up. I've changed the following with fireBug and it looks normal for me now.

To move the right nav over.

`.righttilenav {margin-right:52px;}`

Setting a minmum height to keep all the elements the same height.

`.col-1-8 {min-height:278px;}`